# JAXB CDATA without eclipselink

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

Is there a way to use **CDATA in JAXB without using EclipseLink API** ?

**JAXB Class :**

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "Documentation")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Documentation {
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AdaptorCDATA.class)
    @XmlValue
    protected String value; //setter & getter implemeted

}
```

**Marshaller Property** : required eclipselink api org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.CharacterEscapeHandler

```
marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), new org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.CharacterEscapeHandler() { // property required for CDATA
            @Override
            public void escape(char[] ac, int i, int j, boolean flag,
            Writer writer) throws IOException {
            writer.write( ac, i, j ); }
            });
```

**Adaptor Class :**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class AdaptorCDATA extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return "<![CDATA[" + arg0 + "]]>";
    }
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to do that in the first place? Any decent XML processor can deal with all ways to escape special characters.